# Test failed to run to completion. Reason:Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I wanted to run the following test:

```
RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {


public ExampleInstrumentedTest() {

}

@ClassRule
public static DeviceAnimationTestRule
        deviceAnimationTestRule = new DeviceAnimationTestRule();

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<My_Activity> mLoginActivityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<My_Activity>(My_Activity.class);

@Rule
public UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();

@Test
public void CreateAndSaveTaskEntity() throws Throwable {

    uiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            com.falah.eats.view.base.screen.My_Activity activity = mLoginActivityTestRule.getActivity();
            activity.getWindow()
                    .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

        }
    });


}
```

But I get the error in the console:

> $ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.xxx.yyy.ExampleInstrumentedTest' com.xxx.yyy.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
>   Client not ready yet..
>   Started running tests
>   Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
>   Empty test suite.

Here is my Gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.demo"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config


}





lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        debuggable true
    }
}



testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

jacoco {
    version = '0.7.9'
}

}



dependencies {
```

//for testing dependencies

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.ext.supportAnnotationsversion"

// Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.rulesVersion"

// Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1"
androidTestImplementation 'com.github.VictorAlbertos:DeviceAnimationTestRule:0.0.2'

androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'

}
```